# AMCL doesn't need a static map?

Tags: navigation, mapping, static-map, map-server, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does AMCL work well without a static map?

I applied nav stack to my own robot and it apparently works well.
However, rxgraph shows that AMCL doesn't use static map served by map_server.
The map is used only by move_base.

I think that **MCL (not AMCL) requires a static map** and
AMCL is designed by improving MCL regarding a computational cost.

AMCL doesn't need it?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45837/amcl-doesn%27t-need-a-static-map?/) by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 721 on 2012-10-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [amcl package](http://www.ros.org/wiki/amcl) requires a map either by [subscribing](http://www.ros.org/wiki/amcl#Subscribed_Topics) to the topic, or calling the [service](http://www.ros.org/wiki/amcl#Services_Called) to get the map

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on 2013-01-29**:
Thank you. I didn't know the parameter "use_static_map" and it can switch whether the static map is used or not.